# How to add listview items in a data table

Tags: vb.net

net. The problem is how can I add listview items in a data table to generate a report/ crystal report. Here is the code i currently used. Anyone who know how to do this or any other solution? Thanks.

```
    Dim dt As New DataTable

    With dt
        .Columns.Add("supplier_id")
        .Columns.Add("supplier_name")
        .Columns.Add("supplier_address")
        .Columns.Add("supplier_data")

    End With
    For Each dr As ListViewItem In Me.lvSupplier.Items

        dt.Rows.Add(dr.SubItems("supplier_id").Text, dr.SubItems("supplier_name").Text, dr.SubItems("supplier_address").Text, dr.SubItems("supplier_data").Text) <--ERROR. NullReferencedException was unhandled.
    Next
    Dim rptDoc As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument
    rptDoc = New CrystalReport1
    rptDoc.SetDataSource(dt)
    Form1.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rptDoc
    Form1.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: What is the problem with this code?

Comment: For Each dr As ListViewItem In Me.lvSupplier.Items

        dt.Rows.Add(dr.SubItems("supplier_id").Text, dr.SubItems("supplier_name").Text, dr.SubItems("supplier_address").Text, dr.SubItems("supplier_data").Text) '<--- on this part. NullReferencedException was unhandled.

Comment: Have you debugged it with breakpoints? Maybe one of dr.SubItems... is null?

Comment: what do you mean of breakpoints? do you mean error? sorry i'm new with vb.net. do you think this code is correct to fill data table with listview items? thanks

Comment: The problem is some of those values are null so it cannot find text of it. You can search "visual studio breakpoint" on youtube for tutorials. So you can check which one is problem